# How to solve this system of equations with 3 unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

OK, of course I can solve a system with three unknowns, but here I have λ as well which is what, a coefficient?!

```
λx + 3y + z = 0
x + (λ + 1)y - z = 0
(2λ - 1)x + 2y + 4z = 0
```

The problem wants me to find values of λ where system has nontrivial solutions.

Comment: Do you know how to set up the determinant for a 3 by 3 matrix?

Comment: Yes, I do. @imranfat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system has solutions for all $\lambda$. If you are looking for unique solutions then you need the determinant of the matrix below to be non-zero:

$$
\left|\begin{matrix} \lambda&3&1\\1&\lambda+1&-1\\2\lambda-1&2&4 \end{matrix}\right|\ne0
$$

This implies that $2\lambda^2-\lambda-6=(2\lambda+3)(\lambda-2)\ne0$. So as long as $\lambda\ne2$ and $\lambda\ne\frac{-3}{2}$ you will have a unique solution to the system. This unique solution is $x=y=z=0$ which is trivial(you can get this by row-reducing the augmented matrix for the system).

If $\lambda=2$ or $\lambda=-\frac{3}{2}$ you will have non-trivial solutions because there will be an infinite family of solutions. For example when $\lambda=2$ you get solutions $y=z$, $x=-2z$ and $z$ can be whatever number you like. So you have the 'line' of solutions:

$$
z\cdot\left(\begin{matrix} -2\\1\\1 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: "Nontrivial" in this context generally excludes $(0,0,0)^T$, which is the only solution when the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Oops, should have checked that.